# PHP, Fatal error: Call to undefined method calling function from another class

Tags: php, function, methods, undefined, call

I have a simple PHP structure.

In admin_keys.php i have:

```
<?php
class admin_keys
{
    public $key;
    private $arr_keys = array("1", "2", "3");
    public function check_key_admin()
    {
        if(in_array($this->key,$this->$arr_keys))
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In ok.php i have:

```
<?php
include_once '../../all_keys.php';
$admin_keys = new admin_keys();
$admin_keys->key = "vailozluon";
$_isAdmin = $admin_keys->check_key();
  if( _isAdmin== false)
  {
    echo 'deo phai';
  }else { echo 'ok';}
?>
```

Im new so just bear with me
I don't know why this is return Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method admin_keys::check_key
any help will be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: `check_key_admin` != `check_key`.

Answer (score 1):

you are refering to function (i.e. check_key()) that does not exists in your `class admin_keys`.
You have function named check_admin_key() but you are trying to access it as check_key() which does not exist apparently throwing an error. So just change the name of the function being called as

```
$_isAdmin = $admin_keys->check_admin_key();
```